# Google map issue in developing android apps by eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

a simple question but I can't figure out the answer.
Can I refer my Google API library by the path of C:\Program Files(x86)... as attached picture below?

[image]

I couldn't display my google map although I have followed this tutorial fully:　http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Any issue that I need to take care of in order to display the map of current location correctly?

Comment: Simply you can do is to add the library project into your workspace and add the reference of library project in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Link to refer for newbies implementing Google Maps Api V2:  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/